# Powershell: how to format Get-Childitem for email?

Tags: email, powershell, format, newline

Simply put, I'm trying to send an email from a Powershell script which lists the contents of a directory.

In order to do this, I'm storing text in a variable, then inserting this variable into `Send-MailMessage`.

My problem is this. When I pipe the object to `Out-String` as follows, it doesn't insert newlines:

```
$mailbody += "<p>" + (get-childitem $path | select-object Name | Out-String -width 40) + "</P>"
```

Obviously, when `Get-Childitem` is entered at the prompt, the output is nicely formatted with newlines, however when stored to a variable then emailed (in an HTML email), there are no newlines, which results in an unreadable, long string of filenames.

How do I do this?

Comment: Could it be that the newlines are there, but are not displaying? In HTML, new lines are treated as whitespace.

Comment: I thought that was the reason, however when I removed the `-BodyAsHtml` switch to make sure the email was sent in plantext, there were still no newlines - just whitespace.

Comment: Do you use Outlook as a mail client? If so, unless you have the "remove extra line breaks from plain text messages" setting turned off, Outlook may be deleting line breaks for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet to do this:

```
get-childitem $path | select-object Name | ConvertTo-Html -fragment
```

It will create a nice table for you that can be sent in an HTML email. The `-fragment` part removes the head and body etc. and gives only the table.

Comment: Hey - it's super easy when you know how. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet? Fill in your environment info.

```
$path = "C:\"
[string] $html = dir $path | ConvertTo-Html

$smptServer = ''
$to = ''
$from = ''
$subject = 'Test'
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smptServer -Subject $subject
```

EDIT - This works, but the email looks like crap. If you want it to look exactly like it does when you do a `dir` in the PowerShell window use this:

```
[string] $html = dir $path | Select Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name | ConvertTo-Html
```